# "SELECT * ..." mysqli parametrized query - how to store results without binding?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to store mysqli query results to array.

My code so far looks like this:

```
function get_nearby_users($Id, $MaxDistance, $RowLimit, $RowLimitOffset)
{
    try
    {
    $query = "SELECT 
                    others.*,
                    Distance(me.Latitude, me.Longitude, others.Latitude, others.Longitude) as Distance

                from 
                    Users me
                join
                    Users others

                where 
                    me.Id = ? 
                and 
                    others.Id != ?

                having Distance < ?

                limit ?,?

        ";

        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('iiiii', $Id, $Id, $MaxDistance, $RowLimitOffset, $RowLimit);
        $stmt->execute();

        // how to fill $rows_array?

    }

    catch(Exception $exc)
    {
        // ...
    }

    return $rows_array;

}
```

How can I put my results to array when my SQL contains something like "SELECT *"?

All tutorials with parametrized queries use bind_result function, but I don't want to create variables for all fields and bind them. There is no other way?

Comment: FWIW, there's no need to do so if using MySql via PDO instead of mysqli. You also get a number of other added benefits, as outlined here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use bind_result to store the record set.

Just use [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to store result set rows as an array.

```
$rows_array = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I have modified your code. Use this:

```
function get_nearby_users($Id, $MaxDistance, $RowLimit, $RowLimitOffset)
{
    try
    {
    $query = "SELECT 
                    others.*,
                    Distance(me.Latitude, me.Longitude, others.Latitude, others.Longitude) as Distance

                from 
                    Users me
                join
                    Users others

                where 
                    me.Id = ? 
                and 
                    others.Id != ?

                having Distance < ?

                limit ?,?

        ";

        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('iiiii', $Id, $Id, $MaxDistance, $RowLimitOffset, $RowLimit);
        $stmt->execute();

        $rows_array = $stmt->fetchAll(); // store result set rows as an array

    }

    catch(Exception $exc)
    {
        // ...
    }

    return $rows_array;

}
```